# Do SSL required to prevent eavesdropping?

Tags: ssl, https

To the best of my knowledge SSL is to prevent only Eavesdropping i.e. plucking the digital data passing across a network. So, to prevent password SSL encrypts the data at the login page and decrypt it at database. Finally it carries information securely. I think this can be implemented even using some encryption algorithms like Md5/SHA/other?

What's the difference between SSL and normal encryption?

Please correct me if any of the above statements are false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSL can not prevent eavesdropping if the CA is not safe. As we have seen lately. The data is encrypted via SSL thats right e.g. not like you mentioned with Hashes(Hashing is not Encryption) its using encryption algorithms. Asynchronous and synchronous algorithms. The Asynchronous encryption is a certificate implementation.

To your question: "Whats the difference"

SSL - is a commonly used and accepted way of using encryption e.g for HTTPS in order to secure HTTP connection (using various encryption techniques) and a solid documentation of handshaking.

SSL is also used to secure different tcp protocols(like mail(smtps, pop3s, imaps), ftp(s), etc..)

Encyrption - is used inside SSL.

SSL is supported in common browsers and server implementations. If you would want to use "normal encryption" you have to implement everything by yourself.

Comment: HTTP uses SSL, but SSL isn't designed for HTTP. It is used in many protocols requiring encrypted communication. I know you didn't precisely say that, but your wording strongly implies it.

Comment: I didnt meant this thats true ;) but i will change my wording in order to keep such implications out of my comments thx

Comment: By using Encryption algorithms can I protect my site from eavesdropping as equivalent to SSL?

Comment: The probability is pretty high that you will not implement something by yourself which is more secure than ssl. The problem with eavesdropping regarding ssl is only the weak point(CA - Certification authority).

Comment: What's the difference between a local CA and trusted CA. Is it just a brand name or differs in security?

Comment: A simple explanation would be that a local ca is something like if you ask me to trust you to keep my money safe. A trusted CA is something like a national bank which says trust us to keep my money safe.

Comment: @fyr, your wording is confusing, re. local/trusted CA. There's no difference in principle between a "local" CA and a widely distributed, often commercial CA. The latter type has distribution agreements with browsers and OSes, to be bundled with them. As such, it's more a distinction between a "local" CA (in that its cert is not bundled by default and has to be imported explicitly, making it practical only at a limited scale, e.g. local institution) and a "bundled" CA. Both ca be "trusted" CAs if you choose to trust them. Only exception is EV CAs that are hard-coded into the browser.

Comment: @Bruno completely true. The term "trusted CA" is most of the times used in combination with the builtin CAs.

Comment: SSL do prevent passive eavesdropping, just without trusted CA, it cannot prevent middleman attack I think.

Answer (score 4):

SSL is a protocol for transmitting encrypted data. It is not an encryption algorithm, *per se*. Though HTTPS uses SSL to encrypt web communications, SSL wasn't built for HTTP and has little to do with login pages, though it is common for login pages to be accessed via HTTPS (and hence SSL). Many secure protocols are carried over SSL.

MD5 and the SHA family aren't encryption algorithms either. They are hashing algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

> To the best of my knowledge SSL is to
>   prevent only Eavesdropping

Incorrect. SSL provides secrecy, integrity, and authentication, and provides a mechanism for you the application to perform authorization. It protects you from eavesdropping, tampering, active man-in-the-middle attacks, truncation attacks, ... It is a lot more than mere encryption.